# Using combvec for full matrix (matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations

I have nxm matrix. I want to use combvec to produce all the possible combinations like this

```
combvec(X(1,:),...,X(m,:))
```

If my matrix is different for each loop. How can I use the combvec syntax? Do I have to separate it by column? But How?

Example:
my matrix

```
L=[25000000 15000000 10000000 5000000 3000000 2000000 1000000 800000 700000 500000 500000 300000 200000 100000 0]
L(2,:)=zeros(1,length(L))
```

How to avoid inputting one by one like this?

```
    combination=combvec([25000000,0],[15000000,0],[10000000,0],[5000000,0],[3000000,0],[2000000,0],[1000000,0],[800000,0],[700000,0],[500000,0],[500000,0],[300000,0],[200000,0],[100000,0],[0,0])';
```

Comment: Can you please provide example input and output data?

Comment: @MatthiasW. I have added an example. Hope it s clear enough. Thks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`combvec` seems to require row vectors, not column vectors. So you need to work tih `L` transposed, so that columns become rows. You can:

1. Build a [cell array](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) where each row of `L` transposed goes to a cell;
2. Call `combvec` using as input a [comma-separated list](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) generated from the cell array.

That is:

```
L = [25000000 15000000 10000000 5000000 3000000 2000000 1000000 800000 700000 500000 500000 300000 200000 100000 0];
L(2,:) = zeros(1,length(L)); %// example input
L2 = mat2cell(L.', ones(1,size(L,2)), size(L,1)); %// step 1
result = combvec(L2{:}); %// step 2
```